# How do I redirect output text back into the command line in Linux?

Tags: linux

How do I redirect the output and redirect it back into the input. Basically to automatically type the text outputted, into the command line.

Like this command:

```
$ locate ifcfg-eth0
```

would normally output:

```
$ /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0
```

instead of clearing the command and creating a new line I want it to do this

```
$ /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0(cursor blinking here)
```

Comment: what about just `$(locate ifcfg-eth0)` ?

Comment: Then see: [How do I set a variable to the output of a command in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4651437/1765658)

Comment: I want to add 'vi' command at the beginning of the output so I can edit the located file.

Comment: KamilCuk and F Hauri, perfect works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

We can do something like this with a tool named [xclip](https://github.com/astrand/xclip)

install xclip on debian

```
sudo apt-get install xclip
```

now use

```
locate ifcfg-eth0 | xclip
```

to paste the output use

```
xclip -o
```

For example:
I have a file named scp.sh. I want to locate and run it.

```
locate scp.sh | xclip
```

then

```
xclip -o | bash
```